# How to alter account activation mail Depending on roles

Tags: 7, emails, users

In account settings ,Account Activation mail settings is general i think so.

I want the account activation mail to be altered. I want to check roles, according to that display the mail messages .

how will i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new rule like this

`EVENT` saying  `After saving a new user account`

```
Conditions saying  User has role(s)  check your role there.
```

`Actions` saying `send mail` you can send the mail what you want in that.

Comment: Then two mail will be send I think

Comment: @RajeevK: how two mail will go. In the account settings he can disable that account activation mail.So only this will go.is that right ?

Comment: Then default mail will be disabled for each user type registration. Suppose there are 5 user type & I want to send custom mail to only 3 type of user registration but simple authenticate user registration will have default alert mail then your solution doesn't work..

Comment: @RajeevK: Yes understood, but he can create new rules and check for roles according to that mail will send for each rules. That is what is question meant i think. Roles and messages.

Comment: You mean several rules for each role. Then it can be done..

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the [hook_mail_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) for overriding the mail, which get send after user_save. You can look into the answer given for this question here --

[Override _user_mail_notify() to NOT send email on user_save() if user status is changed](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63684/override-user-mail-notify-to-not-send-email-on-user-save-if-user-status-is)

Though question is not relevant but the answer is.

Comment: I want to alter only for account activation.Not for all.

Comment: @NewToDrupal - This won't alter all the mail but you can write your logic inside and alter only that mail which you want to target. Like for account activation of usertype one.. It totally depends upon you to write the logic..